# Get contents of the first cell in the clicked column and the first cell of the clicked row in a HTML table

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using the following javascript to get the data in a clicked table cell:

```
var table = document.getElementById('ThisWeek'),
    cells = table.getElementsByTagName('td');

for (var i=0,len=cells.length; i<len; i++)
{
    cells[i].onclick = function()
    {
        document.getElementById("txtVal").value = this.innerText;
    }
}
```

How can I modify this so I can also obtain the contents of the first cell in the clicked column and the first cell in the clicked row? E.g. if I click on "s" in the table below, I get the results "2" and "B" returned as two variables:

```
0 1 2 3
A q w e
B a s d
C z x c
```

Please note that I need a javascript solution, not jQuery. Ideally, I would also like clicks on the first row and first column to return empty strings.

Comment: You can use `table.rows` and `rows[n].cells` collections + `rowIndex` and `cellIndex` properties of `tr`s and `td`s. I'd also delegated the event handling to `table` itself, when you better use a proper event attachment with `addEventListener()`. Please do some search at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM) for all those properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This snippet uses the properties I've mentioned in my comment:

```
window.onload = function () {
    var table = document.getElementById('table');
    table.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        var target = e.target,
            col = target.cellIndex,
            row;
        while (target = target.parentElement) {
            if (!col && col !== 0) {
                col = target.cellIndex;
            }
            if (target.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'tr') {
                row = target.rowIndex;
                break;
            }               
        }
        console.log(table.rows[row].cells[0].innerHTML + ', ' + table.rows[0].cells[col].innerHTML);
    });
}
```

[A live demo at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vS7gU/).

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest:

```
function index(c){
    var i = 0;
    while (c.previousSibling){
        /* if the previousSibling has a nodeType and that nodeType === 1 
           (indicating the previousSibling is an element) increment the i variable */
        if (c.previousSibling.nodeType && c.previousSibling.nodeType === 1){
            i++;
        }
        // reset c to the previousSibling
        c = c.previousSibling;
    }
    /* i is the count of previous-siblings, and therefore the index
       amongst those siblings: */
    return i;
}

function getHeaders(e){
    /* this is the table element,
       e.target is the clicked element */
    var el = e.target,
        text = 'textContent' in document ? 'textContent' : 'innerText',
        headers = [el.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('td')[0][text],this.getElementsByTagName('tr')[0].getElementsByTagName('td')[index(el)][text]];
    // set the text of the nextElementSibling of the table:
    this.nextElementSibling[text] =  headers.join(', ');
}

document.getElementById('table').addEventListener('click', getHeaders);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/9Y6CK/1/).

Comment: This fails, if there's an element inside a `td`... Nice `textContent`/`innerText` detection though, I'm going to use it ; ).

Answer (score 1):

You can add this to your cells[i].onclick function:

```
var row = this.parentElement; // TR
var table = row.parentElement.parentElement; // TBODY > TABLE
document.getElementById("columnVal").value = row.rowIndex && this.cellIndex ? table.rows[0].cells[this.cellIndex].innerText : "";
document.getElementById("rowVal").value = row.rowIndex && this.cellIndex ? row.cells[0].innerText : "";
```